# Derivative of $\ \ Trace(GG^T GG^T)\ \ $ with respect to G

Tags: matrices, derivatives

I have an objective function like this: 
$\min\limits_G\ f(G) = \rVert A - GG^T \rVert_F^2 = trace(A^TA)-2\ trace(A^TGG^T)+trace(GG^TGG^T)$
For computing $\frac{d f(G)}{d G}$ using [The Matrix Cookbook, Page 13], I know the derivative of the second term is: $-2AG$ because $A$ is a symetric $n \times n$ matrix, but I don't know $\frac{d}{d G} trace(GG^TGG^T)$?

Thanks :)

Comment: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: What is the *definition* of $\frac{d}{dG}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $f(G)=\mathrm{Tr}(GG^TGG^T)$ to get the derivative you can compute $f(G+H)-f(G)$ and drop all the terms with more than one $H$ as they are $O(\Vert H\Vert^2)$.

More precisely:
$$ f(G+H)-f(G)=\mathrm{Tr}(HG^TGG^T)+\mathrm{Tr}(GH^TGG^T)+\mathrm{Tr}(GG^THG^T)+\mathrm{Tr}(GG^TGH^T)+O(\Vert H\Vert^2)$$
using $\mathrm{Tr}(AB)=\mathrm{Tr}(BA)$ and $\mathrm{Tr}(A^TB)=\mathrm{Tr}(AB^T)$ you can obtain:
$$f(G+H)-f(G)=4 \mathrm{Tr}(G^TGG^T H) +O(\Vert H\Vert^2)$$

Comment: Do you mean $\frac{d}{d G}\ trace(GG^TGG^T) = 4\ G^TGG^T\ $?

Comment: As pointed out in the comments it depends of your definition of $\frac{d}{dG}$ but I think that it is the case.

Comment: I don't know the exact definition of $\frac{d}{d G}$, but I thought for optimizing the equation by some methods that are based on the gradient, I should find the derivative of $\ trace(GG^TGG^T)$ with respect to $G$

Comment: Using [The Matrix Cookbook, eq.123] and cyclic property of trace function, I think but I'm not sure $\frac{\partial}{\partial G}\ trace(GG^TGG^T) = 4\ GG^TG$

Comment: It depends of the defintion of $\frac{d}{dG}$. If the definition is:
$$f(G+H)-f(G)=\mathrm{Tr}\left( \frac{df}{dG} H^T  \right) $$
the computation in my answer give indeed $\frac{d f}{dG} = 4 G G^T G$.
If it is $f(G+H)-f(G)=\mathrm{Tr}\left( \frac{df}{dG} H  \right) $ then it is $G^T G G^T$.